# IE ругается на недопустимый знак

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Не могу передать переменную v

```js
$('.services_li1st').on("click", function() {
  var _url = window.location.href;
  var _data = $(this).val();
  location.href = _url;
});
$(".select").change(function() {
  $("#form_schedule").submit();
});
$(".sh_day").change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  var d = $(".sh_day :selected").html();
  $(".schedule-table-body .schedule-item").css("display", "none");
  $(`.schedule-table-body .schedule-item[data-day="${v}"]`).css("display", "block");
  $('.td_day').text(d);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE не поддерживает [String Templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility), поэтому стоит использовать конкатенацию

```
$('.schedule-table-body .schedule-item[data-day="'+v+'"]')
```